# How to delete path to file with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have got a little problem with PHP code.

I have got an array like this: `var_dump($array);`

```
array(10) {
    [0]=> string(69) "/omd/sites/test/etc/icinga/conf.d/objects/Testrechner/Ethernetbox2.cfg"
    [1]=> string(70) "/omd/sites/test/etc/icinga/conf.d/objects/Testrechner/Ethernetbox1.cfg"
    [2]=> string(68) "/omd/sites/test/etc/icinga/conf.d/objects/Testrechner/test-esx-1.cfg"
    [3]=> string(83) "/omd/sites/test/etc/icinga/conf.d/objects/Testrechner/station-1/sw-disc-test2_11.cfg"
}
```

I want to extract only the filename:

```
"sw-disc-test2_11.cfg"
```

I ahve tried the following:

```
<?PHP

foreach($array as $key => $value) {

    $regex = "#^/omd/[/w\-/]*/$#";
    $replace = '';
    $array[$key] = preg_replace($regex,$replace,$value);
    $array_new = array_map('trim', $array);
    $array_new = array_merge($array_new);

}

var_dump($array_new);

?>
```

With `vardump($array_new)`, I got the same result as with `var_dump($array);`.

I doesn't see my mistake.

Comment: Do you want to capture filename only from last element of array or from each element of array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **[basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)** like this

```
$array_new = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    $array_new[] = basename($value);
}

 var_dump($array_new);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array_old = array(); // your array
$array_new = array(); // new empty array
foreach($array_old as $v){
    $explode = explode('/', $v);
    $array_new[] = end($explode); // here is file name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For completion, here is one way to do it with regex:

```
$regex = '~/\K[^/]+$~';
// for loop...
  if (preg_match($regex, $yourstring, $value)) {
        $array[$key] = $m[0];
     }
```